# Validation of ServiceMetadataDerivedType failed

Tags: oracle12c, middleware, esb, soa, osb

**Validation of ServiceMetadataDerivedType failed:  not found**

I tried running without deploying the application. I tried to run a pipeline in Jdev but it is throwing this error in test console. Tried restarting my machine also, but no luck. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the question, do not know how to go about. Last time somebody has deleted my answer. So here is the answer: When I first deploy it on WebLogic, and then run the pipeline, it ran successfully.